# How to align paragraph div

Tags: html, css

Edit: I realized what I asked was very vague. I;m trying to move a paragraph to the right-center of the site. It is a landing page that I am trying to make, I am not sure what's causing the paragraph block to not move from its original spot. Below is the HTMl/CSS that I am using.

I've tried using margins, float, text-align

```
#test {
  background-color: #000;
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dod6u4bjy/image/upload/v1557191977/matteo-kutufa-1135337-unsplash.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position:fixed;
}

#testnav {
  margin: 50px 220px;
  list-style: none;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 165px 50px;
}
 #testnav a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
 }

 #testnav a {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-decoration: none;
   width: 100px;
}

 li {
   margin: 4px 0;
 }

 #socialnav li{
   display:inline;
   color: pink;
 }

 #socialwrap {
   margin: 0 220px;
}
 #socialwrap a:hover{
   opacity: 0.7;
   color: pink;
 }

 #logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.paragraph{
  border: solid black 1px;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

#intro {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}

</style>
```

```
<body id="test">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dod6u4bjy/image/upload/v1557197589/geisha.png" id="logo" alt=""></a>

<ul id="testnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="socialwrap">
  <ul id="socialnav">
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="paragraph">
<div id="intro">This is a new website concept dedicated to my love the Japanese culture. <br>I hop to bring this idea to the masses.</div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `div` and add the `class="paragraph"` to the `<p>` element instead?

Comment: `text-align: center;` can make it position to the top center of the page.

Comment: Your snippet does not demonstrate the problem; the paragraph is not at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unclear. If you want the text at the top right try this:

```css
.paragraph{
  Color: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
  <p >This is a new website concept dedicated to my   love the Japanese culture. <br>I hop to bring this idea to the masses.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "at the top", but the following will center your text in the middle. To do this you need to set the inner block both have a width and set it to display as inline-block. Then set the outer div to have text-align of center.

```css
.paragraph{
  border: solid black 1px;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

#intro {
  border: solid red 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
<div id="intro">This is a new website concept dedicated to my love the Japanese culture. <br>I hop to bring this idea to the masses.</div>
</div>
```

Note: When dealing with alignment it is often good to use a border to test where the blocks actually start and end. I have put a sample border in the above code. You can adjust the code and then remove the border when you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `flexbox` method to make the paragraph top center. Try the demo.

```css
.paragraph {
  Color: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.paragraph p {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
<p>This is a new website concept dedicated to my love the Japanese culture. <br>I hop to bring this idea to the masses.</p>
</div>
```

`Center Center` aligned paragraph below snippet.

```css
.paragraph {
  Color: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:500px; /*optional */
}
.paragraph p {
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
<p>This is a new website concept dedicated to my love the Japanese culture. <br>I hop to bring this idea to the masses.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but still getting the same results. I feel like it's gotta be something in my html or other css code that's preventing the text to move to the top right center of the page.

Comment: You want to move the text to top right? or center center? `top right center` not available.

Comment: @P.Murtagh My code text aligned top center add the height to paragraph you can see the difference.